# Jackson annotations broken in Scala from 1.9 to 2.1

Tags: java, scala, jackson

Just upgraded Jackson from 1.9 to 2.1 and immediately noticed that `@(JsonProperty@field)` annotations are broken. Note the special `@field` for Scala case classes. Here's a sample:

```
case class Watcher(
  @(JsonProperty@field)("guid")
  @(RiakKey@field)
  val guid: String,

  @(JsonProperty@field)("socialNetwork")
  val socialNetwork: String, // instragram, twitter
)
```

When I go to pull a Watcher serialized as JSON from the database, Jackson goes to deserialize it and it throws the exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "guid" (class com.domain.SocialStreamService.models.Watcher), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
```

Now since this was working in `1.9`, I am assuming something has changed. Anyone know the cause of the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was caused by a namespace issue and the fact that I was using Jerkson (which still pulled in 1.x as a dependency, thus not throwing compiler errors). To solve the issue, I had to go change the namespaces from `com.codehaus` to `com.fasterxml`.

In the meantime, there is a legacy introspector for those who need it: https://github.com/Laures/jackson-legacy-introspector