# Reading snake_case attributes as camelCase in Play Json

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to extract json as a case class within Play application. The attributes in case class are defined in camelCase and json data comes in snake_case.

```
case class User(userId: Long, userName: String)
```

and json would be like this
    {"user_name":"Vishal","user_id":67}

Is there an easy way to instruct play json to automatically do the mapping and extract, like providing some annotations etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a quite old question, but I didn't find any answer for it, so I went to the Play JSON Github repository and found this:

```
implicit val config = JsonConfiguration(SnakeCase)

implicit val userReads: Reads[PlayUser] = Json.reads[PlayUser]
```

So, now seems that exists an official way of doing this

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/d96d42e4baa2261d0e0a9c36518f6921e247e402/documentation/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/json/code/ScalaJsonAutomatedSpec.scala#L128

Comment: This is really useful but is available only in the upcoming 2.6 release. [Expected April-May 2017](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11sVi1-REAIDFVHvwBrfRt1uXkBzROHQYgmcZNGJtDnA/edit).

Comment: this is the good way to do it now, this should be the approuved answer

Answer (score 1):

*See [@GlauberCampinho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173632/897024) for the official solution for this issue,

which didn't exist at the time of writing there this answer.*

---

Play uses Jackson. In Java, you can use the Jackson annotation `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty` on your properties to set the names manually. The argument for the `value` parameter will be used as the key's name.

```
@JsonProperty("user_name")
String userName;
```

I don't know if this also works in Play using Scala. Based on the comments in this [thread about Scala and Jackson](http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/scala-and-jackson?commentId=5286555%3AComment%3A877) the syntax for deserialisation should be something like this:

```
class User @JsonCreator()( @JsonProperty("user_id") val userId:Long, @JsonProperty("user_name") val userName:String )
```

You can find another example of Jackson annotations in a *case class* in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255101/jackson-annotations-broken-in-scala-from-1-9-to-2-1).

Comment: Jackson `@JsonProperty` doesn't work with Play Macros. So if you use Json.format[User] you should look for @GlauberCampinho answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Play 2's JSON Inception, then No. If you're not, then you can just use the @JsonProperty annotations.

I was trying to get this to work with JSON Inception for a few days using various forms and configurations of jerkson/jackson annotations with no such luck!

Answer (score 0):

For Play Json 2.x: https://github.com/tototoshi/play-json-naming

This seems to satisfy *exactly* what I'm looking for, hopefully it helps!